# Ignore extras during model_dump

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm looking for a way to get a dictionary representation of a nested pydantic model which does not include extra elements. `model_dump` offers a number of `exclude` flags, but unfortunately no `exclude_extras`.

Here's an example. I want the assertion to hold. Bear in mind this is just a minimal example, in reality I'm dealing with much more complex models with multiple nested layers each of which can hold extra data.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict


class Nested(BaseModel):

    model_config = ConfigDict(extra="allow")

    baz: str


class Root(BaseModel):

    foo: int = 10
    bar: int
    nested: Nested


if __name__ == "__main__":

    model = Root(foo=10, bar=20, nested={"baz": "boing", "extra": "so special"})

    dumped_data = model.model_dump()

    assert "extra" not in dumped_data["nested"]
```

The idea I'm currently exploring is to iterate the model after dumping and manually prune the result using `model_extra`. But it feels like there should be a less tedious way.

Comment: May be you need to `pip install --upgrade pydantic`

Comment: Do you need these extra fields exist in your model object? If you want just ignore them you can use `model_config = ConfigDict(extra='ignore')`.

Comment: @YuriiMotov thanks, but yes, I need them in the models, but want to remove them in the dump.

Comment: If you need to have extra fields in your objects, but exclude them during serialization, I have a feeling that this can be done using `model_serializer(mode="wrap")`, but I don't know how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your `MyBaseModel` class from `BaseModel`, where you can add model serializer (with mode="wrap").

In this model serializer just exclude from result dict all fields which are not present in the `self.model_fields`.

Now inherit all your models from `MyBaseModel` and enjoy!

```
from typing import Any
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict, model_serializer, SerializerFunctionWrapHandler, FieldSerializationInfo


class MyBaseModel(BaseModel):
    @model_serializer(mode="wrap")
    def _serialize(self, handler):
        d = handler(self)
        d = {k:v for k, v in d.items() if k in self.model_fields}
        return d


class Nested(MyBaseModel):

    model_config = ConfigDict(extra="allow")

    baz: str


class Root(MyBaseModel):

    foo: int = 10
    bar: int
    nested: Nested


if __name__ == "__main__":

    model = Root(foo=10, bar=20, nested={"baz": "boing", "extra": "so special"})

    dumped_data = model.model_dump()

    assert "extra" not in dumped_data["nested"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Update: For Pydantic 2.x and if you are looking to exclude a nested key for all occurances, you can use the key `__all__` like so:

`dumped_data = model.model_dump(exclude={'__all__': {'extra'}})`

Example from Documentation (https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/serialization/#advanced-include-and-exclude):

```
class User(BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    second_name: str
    address: Address
    card_details: CardDetails
    hobbies: List[Hobby]
user = User(
    first_name='John',
    second_name='Doe',
    address=Address(
        post_code=123456, country=Country(name='USA', phone_code=1)
    ),
    card_details=CardDetails(
        number='4212934504460000', expires=datetime.date(2020, 5, 1)
    ),
    hobbies=[
        Hobby(name='Programming', info='Writing code and stuff'),
        Hobby(name='Gaming', info='Hell Yeah!!!'),
    ],
)
(...)
print(user.model_dump(exclude={'hobbies': {'__all__': {'info'}}}))
```

Comment: `dict()` function doesn't serialize nested elements. It will just include them as is..

Comment: according to the advanced include and exclude section, nested elements can be excluded. https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/exporting_models/#advanced-include-and-exclude

i have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I think this is not the thing TS needs. Pydantic is usually used to validate user data and you don't know what extra fields user include in this data.. In this case, you don't know the names of the fields that need to be excluded.

Comment: a) This is pydantic v1 code, I'm using v2 and b) I don't want to explicity list all the extra items. I'm looking for a way to remove them without listing them

Comment: thanks, i understand now. is the edited answer what you were looking for?